# Truncate at Page Break CKeditor Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, truncate

i have blog with ruby on rails and using ckeditor for editor text. I need to truncate my post at page break for printing from ckeditor.

example post beforetruncate

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
<span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</p>
```

how do automatically truncate before save when it encounters this element?

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
<span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

post aftertruncate

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
```

on model

```
before_save :truncate_post

def truncate_post
  self.aftertruncate = ......
end
```

thanks for help..